# Deviation of sum of highest values

Tags: probability

Suppose that $n$ random variables are drawn uniformly and independently from $[0,1]$. We know from Chernoff that the probability that their sum is greater than $\frac12n(1+\varepsilon)$ is exponentially small in $n$.

What about the sum of the **highest** $n/2$ values from among these $n$ values? The expected value is close to $\frac38n$ (when $n$ is large). Is the probability that this sum is greater than $\frac38n(1+\varepsilon)$ also exponentially small in $n$?

Comment: Why is the expected value  $3/8 n$, not $3/4 n$? I am trying to understand the problem.

Comment: Also, it is unclear what you mean by "exponentially small  in $\epsilon$".

Comment: If $n=20$, the expected values of the highest $10$ numbers are $20/21, 19/21, ..., 11/21$, with sum $155/21\approx (3/8)(20)$. And I mean exponentially small in $n$ instead of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Aren't both just a consequence of the Central Limit Theorem ?

Comment: Can you show how and which version of CLT you're using? The basic version assumes i.i.d. random variables like Chernoff, so it doesn't work for here.

Comment: Also, the usual Central Limit Theorems usually do not guarantee a very strong rate of convergence.  As discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/error-in-normal-approximation-to-a-uniform-sum-distribution , the CDF between the sum of $n$ uniform variables and the rescaled normal distribution can be roughly $c/n$ apart from each other, which dwarfs the exponential tail bound we're looking for.  Chernoff-style arguments focus on the tail of the distribution, and give much stronger boudns there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an alternative version of Chernoff's inequality known as [McDiarmid's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_martingale#McDiarmid.27s_inequality) (based off of Azuma's martingale inequality) that is applicable here.  Basically the inequality says that if you have a function of $n$ independent variables which is "bounded in single coordinate differences" (changing one variable while leaving the others fixed can only change the function by a constant), then you have similar guarantees to the Chernoff bounds.

Since changing a single term can affect the sum of the largest $n/2$ variables by at most $1$, this immediately gives an exponential bound.

Comment: I might understand something wrong, but once we consider the largest $n/2$ variables we cannot say that they're "independent", can we?

Comment: The key here is to think of the function as taking all $n$ variables as input, not just the largest $n/2$ (so the function receives $n$ numbers and returns the sum of the largest $n/2$).  This way the inputs remain independent.

Comment: I see. The bound obtained is $\exp\left(-\frac{2\varepsilon^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{2\varepsilon^2}{n}\right)$. Doesn't that converge to $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: You're looking for an (additive) deviation of $\epsilon n$, not $\epsilon$, so the bound ends up being $\exp\left(-\frac{2 (\epsilon n)^2}{n}\right)=\exp\left(-2 \epsilon^2 n\right)$

Answer (score 3):

This is true, and all you need is Cramer's large deviation principle. Let your iid uniform variables be $\mathbb X = \{X_k,k= 1,\dots,n\}$, First note for any $\delta>0$, the probability that less than $n/2$ numbers from $\mathbb X$ are greater than $(1-\delta)/2$ is exponentially small. Therefore, the probability that the sum of $n/2$ largest numbers from $\mathbb{X}$ exceeds $3(1+\varepsilon)n/8$ is at most the probability that the sum of all numbers from $\mathbb{X}$ larger than $(1-\delta)/2$ exceeds $3(1+\varepsilon)n/8$, plus some exponentially small term. 
The last one you can rewrite as
$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \mathbf{1}_{X_{k}>(1-\delta)/2}>\frac{3}8(1+\varepsilon).\tag{1}
$$
Note that
$$
\mathsf{E} [X_1 \mathbf{1}_{X_{1}>(1-\delta)/2}] = \frac12\left(1-\Big(\frac{1-\delta}2\Big)^2\right)<\frac{3}{8}(1+\varepsilon)
$$
for small enough $\delta$. Therefore, $(1)$  has exponentially small probability for small $\delta$ due to Cramer's LDP (applied to $\{X_k\mathbf{1}_{X_{k}>(1-\delta)/2},k=1,\dots,n \}$).

Comment: what does LDP stand for?

Comment: How do you make the last conclusion ("which has exponentially small probability for small $\delta$")?

Comment: @pi66, is it clear now?

Comment: @zhoraster It would be great if you could add a reference. I searched for "Cramer's large deviation principle" and it's not so clear what the statement says exactly. For instance, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) has a statement but with i.i.d. random variables.

Comment: @pi66, see [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory#Large_deviations_for_sums_of_independent_random_variables). The variables are iid, I've edited the answer a little bit.